# I can't show the content of the objects of my service.

Tags: angular, service, ngfor

I want to put on a HTML component, the variables of objects which become from a service. And I can't.

My component is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Profesional, ProfesionalService} from '../../profesional.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-gestion-profesionales',
  templateUrl: './gestion-profesionales.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gestion-profesionales.component.css']
})
export class GestionProfesionalesComponent implements OnInit {
  prof = new Array<Profesional>();
  tags;



  constructor(private profesionalService: ProfesionalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.allProf();
  }
    allProf(): void {
    this.profesionalService.getProfesionales()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.prof= data;
        console.log(this.prof);

      });
  }
}
```

My service is :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Profesional {
  ID: number;
  Name: string;
  College: string;
  DNI: string;
  Surname: string;
  Email: string;
  Password: string;
  Phone: string;
  Photo: string;
}


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class ProfesionalService {

  private profesionalesUrl = 'https://h205.eps.ua.es:8080/profesionales';  // URL to web api

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  /** GET obtenemos todos los profesionales */
  getProfesionales (): Observable<Profesional[]> {
    return this.http.get<Profesional[]>(this.profesionalesUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(profesionales => this.log(`fetched profesionales`)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getProfesionales', []))
      );
  }
}
```

And when I do the request, everything is OK. The JSON response is like this:

```
Object results:
Array(35)
0: {ID: "1", DNI: "71955507F", College: "mimi", Name: "pepe", Surname: "popo", …}
1: {ID: "_09y4nb7b1", DNI: "434632tnm", College: "siuno", Name: "Matasanos", Surname: "Berenguer Pastor", …}
```

So, I have problems to show on my HTML component the info. I want to do it with ng-for, but it doesn't work. It appears this error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Phone number</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
 <tbody>

   <tr *ngFor="let item of prof">
    <td>{{ item.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.Surname }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.Phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.Email }}</td> 
   </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

Maybe is due to the variable prof that is form by Profesional instances. I don't know how to show the info in the correct way.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverFlow! What happens if you assign your `prof` variable to an hard written array of values ? I mean, just copy a slice of the result from the api into your code and see.

Comment: can you share the JSON instead of Object Result?

Answer (score 0):

you got JSON array not Javascript Object from api, that's why when javascript try to loop that's show the error, because your try gets an object you don't have.

Use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON) function in order to convert it to JS object.

change these line

```
this.prof = data
```

with

```
this.prof = JSON.parse(data);
```

so it's like this

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.allProf();
  }
    allProf(): void {
    this.profesionalService.getProfesionales()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.prof = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(this.prof);

      });
  }
```